# Convert EJSON to JSON with Mongo Realm App function

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, realm

I have created a simple Realm App that will use a HTTPS endpoint to run a function which runs an aggregation pipeline.

The function looks like this...

```js
exports = async function (request, response) {

const pipeline = [
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 0
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$vaultId', 
      'vaultName': {
        '$first': '$vaultName'
      }, 
      'vaultContract': {
        '$first': '$vaultContract'
      }, 
      'prices': {
        '$push': {
          'readingDate': '$readingDate', 
          'spotPrice': '$spotPrice'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      '_id': 1, 
      'readingDate': -1
    }
  }
];


requestResponse = await context.services
    .get("mongodb-atlas")
    .db("mydb")
    .collection("mycollection")
    .aggregate(pipeline);

return requestResponse;
};
```

When setting up the HTTPS endpoint I have the option of choosing the return type as JSON or EJSON. When choosing EJSON it works fine but includes additional details in the response that are not required.  When switching to JSON there response fails.

At the moment the response looks like this...

```json
...
,
  {
    "vaultId": {
      "$numberInt": "552"
    },
    "vaultName": "RR/BAYC",
    "vaultContract": "0xcd2e3a66507e94190e3b1521a189ad821c8c3006",
    "prices": [
      {
        "readingDate": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1656295562871"
          }
        },
        "spotPrice": {
          "$numberDouble": "0.18317855743872674"
        }
      },
      {
        "readingDate": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1656381961889"
          }
        },
        "spotPrice": {
          "$numberDouble": "0.253926321676319"
        }
      },
      {
        "readingDate": {
          "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1656468400214"
          }
        },
        "spotPrice": {
          "$numberDouble": "0.23309041730430674"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
...
```

but I'm looking for it to be

```json
...,
  {
    "vaultId": "552",
    "vaultName": "RR/BAYC",
    "vaultContract": "0xcd2e3a66507e94190e3b1521a189ad821c8c3006",
    "prices": [
      {
        "readingDate": "1656295562871",
        "spotPrice": "0.18317855743872674"
      },
      {
        "readingDate": "1656381961889",
        "spotPrice": "0.253926321676319"
      },
      {
        "readingDate": "1656468400214",
        "spotPrice": "0.23309041730430674"
        }
    ]
  },
...
```

I've added `ejson` as a dependency on the app and added in the following

```js
requestResponse = await context.services
    .get("mongodb-atlas")
    .db("mydb")
    .collection("mycollection")
    .aggregate(pipeline);

let newData = await EJSON.stringify(requestResponse);
return newData;
};
```

but I get back

```
> result: 
"{}"
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('"{}"')
```

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: `requestResponse = await context.services` is an iterator. `EJSON.stringify` is not a promise, no need to await.   `"readingDate"` is a Date, EJSON will convert it to ISO 8601 string, not milliseconds epoch string. `When switching to JSON there response fails.` - don't change code after switching to JSON, just `return requestResponse;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AlexBlex . I'm not sure what you mean by `don't change code after switching to JSON`, is it possible to change this to plain JSON instead of the EJSON ?

Comment: It's your words: "When setting up the HTTPS endpoint I have the option of choosing the return type as JSON or EJSON." If you need json - choose json.

Comment: @AlexBlex right, good point. I should have pointed out that when I set it to JSON I get an error in the logs "failed to set response". I assume that is because the response is coming out as EJSON and needs to be changed to JSON in the function call.

Comment: You need to tell more about your set up really. I just tried a function with HTTP endpoint configured to return json and tested it with your document - it returns valid json. See screenshots in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did, but this works out of box:

Function **ejson**:

```
exports = function(arg){
    return context.services.get("mongodb-atlas")
      .db("so")
      .collection("SO72801121")
      .find({})
  
};
```

[image]

The endpoint with **json** output uses the **ejson** function:

[image]

The result: https://us-east-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/application-0-ioxbi/endpoint/SO72801121

[image]